# Create Rank of tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples, rank

How do i do this? 
starting with this sample

```
         Id,  Id2    CCC
        [  (A123 A120 '2011-03'), 
  LL=     (A133 A123 '2011-03'),
         ( D123 D120 '2011-04'),
          (D140 D123 '2011-04'),]
```

I.m trying to get this, Adding rank to each tuple.

```
     [(A123, A120 ,'2011-03',1), 
  LL=     (A133, A123, '2011-03',2),
         ( D123, D120, '2011-04',3),
          (D140, D123, '2011-04',4),]


    for i in range(len(LL)):
        RowId = i+1
        LL.append(RowId)
```

I get something like this:

```
        [(A123, A120 ,'2011-03'), 
  LL=     (A133, A123, '2011-03),
         ( D123, D120, '2011-04),
          (D140, D123, '2011-04),1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pprint
LL= [ ('A123', 'A120', '2011-03'),
      ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03'),
      ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04'),
      ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04'),]
LL = [row+(i,) for i,row in enumerate(LL,1)]
pprint.pprint(LL)
```

yields

```
[('A123', 'A120', '2011-03', 1),
 ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03', 2),
 ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04', 3),
 ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04', 4)]
```

---

Here's a bit of explanation:

We start with `LL` defined like this:

```
In [28]: LL
Out[28]: 
[('A123', 'A120', '2011-03'),
 ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03'),
 ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04'),
 ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04')]
```

The first trick is to use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
In [30]: list(enumerate(LL))
Out[30]: 
[(0, ('A123', 'A120', '2011-03')),
 (1, ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03')),
 (2, ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04')),
 (3, ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04'))]
```

which is close to what you want, except that the "rank" starts counting at 0, and is placed in front of the row instead of at the end. We can tell `enumerate` to start counting with 1, using `enumerate(LL,1)`, and we can place the rank at the end of the row using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [31]: [row+(i,) for i,row in enumerate(LL,1)]
Out[31]: 
[('A123', 'A120', '2011-03', 1),
 ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03', 2),
 ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04', 3),
 ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04', 4)]
```

In the list comprehension, `row` is a tuple like `('A123', 'A120', '2011-03')`,
and `row+(i,)` is a sum of tuples:

```
In [32]: ('A123', 'A120', '2011-03')+(1,)
Out[32]: ('A123', 'A120', '2011-03', 1)
```

This is how each row of the list comprehension is constructed.

Comment: Something  wierd with this. Using LL = pprint.pprint([row+(i,) for i,row in enumerate(LL,1)]). To continue processing LL. And get errors. LL needs to stay in list type.

Comment: @user428862: To redefine `LL` use `LL = [row+(i,) for i,row in enumerate(LL,1)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate to create rank variables(added 1 for starting from 1), and create a new list of new tuples, because tuples are immutable, thats why we are creating new tuples.

Example, should work on your list too:

```
In [1]: LL=[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]

In [2]: [j+(i+1,) for i,j in enumerate(LL)]
Out[2]: [(1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(LL)):
        RowId = i+1
        LL[i].append(RowId)
```

Please test it.

Comment: ohh. you can't add elements to a tuple once they are created :)
Why dont you use the list instead ?